# Project reactor spring webflux switch

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm wondering what's the best practices to make a kind of switch in spring webflux.

I mean, let's suppose I need to understand and incoming parameter (e.g. request param), in a classical way I'd write

```
switch(param){
  case 1:
    return 1;
  case 2:
    return 2;
}
```

In a reactive way what's is the best practice?
In order to avoid blocking code outside the non blocking side I was think to something like this

```
return Mono.just(param).flatMap(p ->{
switch(p){
  case 1:
    return 1;
  case 2:
    return 2;
}
});
```

Is it correct? Is there a better solution?

Comment: that should work

Comment: Well, provided `switch` is not a blocking code. You can use simple `map`. Provided  solution with `flatMap` won't compile since you should return Mono/Flux from it